# How can I visualize trailing whitespace like this?

Tags: whitespace

I've tried to configure whitespace-mode to do what I want but with no luck. I'm trying to achieve the following (see image).

[image]

Comment: I had to download the picture and change the contrast before I could tell what you are trying to achieve. In case others have the same problem, trailing whitespace is displayed as dots ·········· in a rather dark gray on black (or even darker gray).

Comment: What about `(setq whitespace-style '(face trailing))`?

Comment: and customizing the face `whitespace-trailing`.

Comment: @JeanPierre I've spent a ton of time trying to tweak `whitespace-style` with no luck

Answer (score 12):

Ignoring `whitespace-mode`, there's always:

```
(setq-default show-trailing-whitespace t)
```

and

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `trailing-whitespace` <kbd>RET</kbd>

which might not give you that exact visualisation, but *will* let you visualise trailing whitespace nevertheless.

I also have a keybinding for this:

```el
(defun toggle-show-trailing-whitespace ()
  "Toggle `show-trailing-whitespace'."
  (interactive)
  (setq show-trailing-whitespace (not show-trailing-whitespace)))
```

For `whitespace-mode` ensure you have `trailing` included in `whitespace-style`, and once again there's a specific face:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `whitespace-trailing` <kbd>RET</kbd>

In either case, I don't know how you'll get spaces to appear as dots *for that face only*, unless you can specify a font which has dots for spaces? Someone else might know otherwise.

Comment: That works, but I find the dots to be more subtle which I like a lot.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation in the emacs [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html#Useless-Whitespace) says:

> Whitespace mode is a buffer-local minor mode that lets you
>   “visualize” many kinds of whitespace in the buffer, by either drawing
>   the whitespace characters with a special face or displaying them as
>   special glyphs.

The relevant docstrings contain more information.  So let's say we
want do display spaces as ·:

```el
(setq whitespace-display-mappings '((space-mark 32 [?·])))
```

Note we could add an entry for `tab-mark` for this to apply to tabs
as well.

Now this is only applied if `whitespace-style` contains `space-mark`:

```el
(setq whitespace-style '(space-mark))
```

The problem is we can't specify different glyphs for different kinds
of spaces (in your case, trailing versus other spaces), but what we
can specify for each kind is a **face** to be used, so we instead do:

```el
(setq whitespace-style '(face trailing spaces space-mark))
```

that is in addition of using the · glyph, we want both *trailing
spaces* and *(non trailing, I guess) spaces* to be displayed by faces.

Now we have to <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-face` `whitespace-space` to a "non visible" face by setting both its `Foreground` and `Background` attributes to
our background color ; and `whitespace-trailing` to whatever we want.

Note that `whitespace-mode` has to be restarted for changes to these
variables to take effect.

Also, non trailing whitespaces will be visible as a · when point is
there if the [`cursor-type`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cursor-Parameters.html#Cursor-Parameters) is a `box`, or when in highlighted region, that can be annoying.

After all, this is a bit convoluted:

- there's a space in the buffer there,
- but it is displayed as a · glyph,
- but its face "hides" it, making it look like a space.

Additionnaly, trailing white spaces are not shown when point is at line end, after these spaces; this is [by design](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html#Useless-Whitespace):

> This feature does not apply when point is at the end of the line containing the whitespace. Strictly speaking, that is “trailing whitespace” nonetheless, but displaying it specially in that case looks ugly while you are typing in new text. In this special case, the location of point is enough to show you that the spaces are present.

If you really want to change this, here is how it's implemented in `whitespace.el`:

```el
(defun whitespace-trailing-regexp (limit)
  "Match trailing spaces which do not contain the point at end of line."
  (let ((status t))
    (while (if (re-search-forward whitespace-trailing-regexp limit t)
               (= whitespace-point (match-end 1)) ;; loop if point at eol
             (setq status nil)))          ;; end of buffer
    status))
```

You can redefine this function in your init file, removing the end of line test:

```el
(defun whitespace-trailing-regexp (limit)
  "Match all trailing spaces. This overloads the definition in whitespace.el."
  (let ((status t))
    (while (unless (re-search-forward whitespace-trailing-regexp limit t)
             (setq status nil)))          ;; end of buffer
    status))
```

Of course, all of this must be done *after* `whitespace` has been loaded, which can be ensured by including `(require 'whitespace)` first.  Another possibility would be to [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions) the function, I'm not sure what's the prefered way here.

Comment: That is very close, with a small exception. See the [first](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/533452/2016-05-01%20at%2018.08.png) and [second](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/533452/2016-05-01%20at%2018.07.png) screenshots.

Comment: @Cezar This is apparently *by design*, see third paragraph of https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html#Useless-Whitespace

Comment: @Cezar ... but I think can be easily fixed by tweaking the code.  I'll update my answer.  Another pitfall, non trailing whitespaces are also visible in highlighted region.

Comment: @JeanPierre in addition, the spaces are visible in the current line if you use `hl-line-mode`.

Comment: @PythonNut Indeed.  Displaying spaces as a dot is done through a display-table and hiding hit with a face is er... a bit of a hack.

Comment: @JeanPierre Thanks, though. I don't think I can bring myself to enable `whitespace-mode` by default, but I'll keep this around in my config. I know there's some instances where it'll come in handy later.