# distinguish inner consecutive spaces

Tags: whitespace, whitespace-mode

I'm aware of and use whitespace-mode to great effect. I don't show a glyph/character for spaces because I think it's too noisy and unnecessary. I do highlight trailing spaces red which is great.

Aside from that, I was thinking that it may be useful to specify a glyph such as `·`, if it were possible, for inner consecutive spaces. This means that it excludes trailing whitespace as well as indentation, for example:

```
print("one·····two");
```

instead of:

```
print("one     two");
```

But again, this wouldn't apply to leading/indentation whitespace nor trailing whitespace.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**: I tried setting `whitespace-regexp-search` as:

```
(setq whitespace-space-regexp "[^ ]\\( \\{2,\\}\\)[^ ]")
```

I have `spaces` and `space-mark` in my `whitespace-style`:

```
(setq whitespace-style
      '(face indentation trailing empty spaces space-after-tab
        space-before-tab tab-mark space-mark))
```

However, it seems like the `whitespace-space-regexp` is only for the `spaces` face highlighting, and isn't used for setting the `space-mark`. Here's the effect:

[image: img]

Notice that all other spaces are still showing the space-mark, even though what I'd like is for consecutive spaces of 2 or more to show it. The inner consecutive spaces are indeed being highlighted differently, but I only did that to show the difference between what's being matched by `whitespace-space-regexp` and the `space-mark` character.

In fact I just noticed that even the numberline is showing the space-mark.

It looks like the `space-mark` is simply matched based on a character, which I guess makes sense, so perhaps this isn't possible after all.

**Note**: As outlined in my post, I recognize that this isn't possible via whitespace itself, what I'm curious about is whether it's possible to do at all. I found some uses of font-locking such as [this one](http://oremacs.com/2015/01/11/pretty-elisp-regex/) which accomplish replacing pattern matches with a character. I'm wondering if it would be possible to use something like this but have it replace the spaces in the region matched with the middle dot for example.

Comment: It is possible to draw an overlay that looks like a middle dot at the desired locations, but it would not be as efficient as setting up a font-lock rule and setting up a highlight of some sort at the desired locations.  The answer by JeanPierre is correct, but doesn't provide either of the above-mentioned solutions/workarounds.

Comment: Yeah I saw some people doing some things with font-lock rules where they would use `compose-region` to like replace one string with another, such as [this one](http://oremacs.com/2015/01/11/pretty-elisp-regex/), but I can't figure out how to make it replace the region with another string or replace all spaces in the region with the middle dot with something like `subst-char-in-region`. Is that even possible?

Comment: @lawlist So that I can enhance my answer, you mean: there's no solution *provided by `whitespace mode`* but one could use overlays to achieve that; right?  What's the second solution/workaround?

Comment: @JeanPierre -- I've given it some thought and don't have a really good solution.  I do a lot of stuff with overlays in the visible window, but I programmatically need to recalculate each command loop -- so depending on what's going on, it may not be that efficient.  I have never been impressed by the composition library, perhaps because it is not 100% compatible with my preferred courier font on OSX.  The easiest and most workable solution would be for the original poster to just settle on a face attribute like overline/underscore/strikethrough instead of a middle dot and use a font-lock rule.

Comment: @lawlist Fair enough, that's good to know. The reason I'm not inclined to just use a face attribute is that the point of using a dot glyph was to give an idea of how many spaces were there. Making it overline, underscore, strikethrough, or even just a background color doesn't serve that end. Thanks for the information though, I'll mark JeanPierre's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you can't specify different glyphs for different kinds of spaces because this feature makes use of a [display table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Tables.html#Display-Tables). The relevant values in variable `whitespace-style` are ([emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html#Useless-Whitespace)):

> space-mark
>       Draw space and non-breaking characters with a special glyph.
>
> tab-mark
>       Draw tab characters with a special glyph.
>
> newline-mark
>       Draw newline characters with a special glyph.

All other values specify *highlights*, so all other distinctions can only be made through the use of faces.

See my answer on a [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21863/how-can-i-visualize-trailing-whitespace-like-this/21961#21961).

Comment: Thanks JeanPierre. I realized this, what I'm wondering about is if it's possible to do in emacs at all, for example via font-locking.